# Java library for working with video - analysis of gestures

Tags: java, image-processing, video-processing, multimedia

I'm looking for a good tool for working with video analysis, I think the best in Java. I would like to be able to detect certain gestures. I mean **sign language**. As for detecting hand movements and what they do. So that eg. The result compared to the pattern. I was wondering about the program through which I can graphically draw the functions of which are moving hands, and then match it to the pattern. Or maybe the best solution would be to write your own library to work under the direction indicated in the video capture gestures.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider taking a look at the [openIMAJ](http://www.openimaj.org/index.html) and [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/). These are two state-of-the-art frame work that you can consider using for your multimedia(video) analysis.